# published .NET framework 3.5 program wants .NET framework 4.7.2 during Instalation

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to publishing my programs so any help will be appreciated.
When starting my solution I've wanted to build it on .NET Framework 4.7.2 but due to system incompatibility with my client OS (1st unupdated ver. of win7), i've had to change to target framework to 3.5.

Even after changing target framework in the properties > application window it still wants to install .net framework 4.7.2 even tho it is unsupported.

Comment: .NET programs do not have installers - so what are you referring to, exactly? Are you using ClickOnce? WIX? MSI?

Comment: FWIW, the .NET Framework 4.5 is available for Windows 7 (non-SP1), and .NET Framework 4.5 will run all competently-written .NET Framework 3.5 programs fine.

Comment: That said, not running SP1 on Windows 7 today is borderline criminal because of the security risks. **There is no legitimate reason to run pre-SP1 Windows 7!**

Comment: @Dai I'm referring to exactly those files generated on publish.
https://imgur.com/a/ecwohvV
When i launch either the clickonce App or setup it prompts that it wants .net framework 4.7.2 installed

Also I am fully aware that a flat version of win7 is dangerous but my client really doesn't want to update it.

Comment: @Dai the download page for .Net Framework 4.5 says that it requires Win7SP1, i've checked it multiple time because of compatibility issues in the code with 3.5.

Comment: I found a workaround that isn't perfect but it works.
i had all the code allready made for .NET Framework 3.5 so i just did a new project from scratch targeted for 3.5 and i just pasted my whole program to the new project.

I know that it isn't at any means optimal in case of huge applications so i'm still waiting for a good answer.

Comment: The published files are using ClickOnce. You would need a different configuration during the Publish

Comment: "but my client really doesn't want to update it." - what excuse does your client have, exactly?